# Changing git branches and recreating environments

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, remote-server

This is more a best practices questions. Sometimes, I'm working on a long term branch and I have to stop it to debug something quick in another branch. In order to do that, I checkout another branch and my project in local and in my remote server changes too (thanks to PhpStorm that connects both). I also do a composer.phar update, doctrine:schema:update and other commands to adapt the project to the new environment. The problem with that is:

1) I waist time changing branchs and using the commands just to debug something quick and then come back to my long term project.

2) The new branch erases new parameters if I had added new ones on the long term branch. I have to remember the values I chose and so on.

3) My database is updated and if I had filled it on the long term branch I loose the content.

The third point is easier to solve. I just have to create another database for the new branch. However, I think I can improve all these steps. Maybe having another folder for the new branche. But how would I do with git that points to only one folder? I would like to know how other developers do that in their everyday work to be more efficient.

Obs: I work on a Symfony project.

Comment: I'm sure it depends on your workflow, but on my projects (applications), I simply clone the repo to a second folder and do my work in that folder. Sounds like you're doing more web work, so that might be more difficult.

Comment: Yes, I work on a web projetc @DarkFalcon.